How to interpret sum of z-scores and average sum of z-scores?
Suppose I have data from 5 sub-tests and 2 groups of participants. What is the difference in the interpretation of a sum of z-scores (i.e, transform all 5 measures into z-scores and sum them up) versus the average sum (i.e, dividing the sum by 5) ?

For example, If I wanted to analyse a model such as lm(scores ~ age + group). What does a "1-unit change" in the predictor variable mean in each context (sum x average sum) ?

Note. In my actual data, if I had enough participants, I would have run a PCA to create the composite score, but I can't do that, this is why I'll go with the z-scores. I need a composite score of the subtests. 
Note2: These are accuracy scores (number of correct answers).

Some dummy-data:

library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

# Generate dummy data
n <- 100  # Number of participants
data <- data.frame(
  participant_id = 1:n,
  age = sample(18:30, n, replace = TRUE),  # Age of participants
  group = sample(c("male", "female"), n, replace = TRUE),  # Group 
  subtest1 = rnorm(n), subtest2 = rnorm(n), subtest3 = rnorm(n), 
  subtest4 = rnorm(n), subtest5 = rnorm(n)
)

# Standardize the subtest scores
data_z <- data %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("subtest"), scale))  %>% # Scale  
  (standardize) subtest scores
  mutate(sum_z_scores = rowSums(select(.,starts_with("subtest"))),   
# Sum of z-scores
    avg_z_scores = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("subtest"))))    
# Average of z-scores

# Fit linear models
model_sum <- lm(sum_z_scores ~ age + group, data = data_z)
model_avg <- lm(avg_z_scores ~ age + group, data = data_z)


The difference is a factor of 5 in the coefficients. You can interpret this as a unit change. It would be the same if your dependent variable was a distance and you changed units from meters to kilometers.
If you divide the left-hand side of an equation by a factor, you also need to divide the right-hand side by the same factor. Since the predictors are unchanged, the factor goes into the coefficients. The position of the sum of squares minimum is not impacted by such a unit change of the dependent variable.
$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{1,i} + \beta_2x_{2,i} + \varepsilon_i\\
\frac{y_i}{5} = \frac{\beta_0}{5} + \frac{\beta_1}{5}x_{1,i} + \frac{\beta_2}{5}x_{2,i} + \frac{\varepsilon_i}{5}$
Hence:
coef(model_sum)
#(Intercept)          age    groupmale 
#0.113514239 -0.001736993 -0.166028258 
coef(model_avg) * 5
#(Intercept)          age    groupmale 
#0.113514239 -0.001736993 -0.166028258 

sum(model_sum$residuals^2)
#[1] 496.5761
sum(model_avg$residuals^2) * 5^2
#[1] 496.5761

So, estimated effect sizes are stronger by a factor of five if you use summed scores compared to averaged scores. But they also have a different unit, you are just not seeing that unit. The actual effects are identical.
However, I don't understand why you sum or average the data. Why don't you do the regression with non-aggregated data? I.e., transform the data to long format and include the subtest as a predictor.
DF <- data %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("subtest"), scale)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("subtest"), names_to = "subtest", values_to = "score")

model <- lm(score ~ (age + group) * subtest, data = DF, 
            contrasts = list(group = contr.treatment, subtest = contr.sum))
#       (Intercept)                age          groupmale           subtest1           subtest2           subtest3           subtest4       age:subtest1 
#      0.0227028479      -0.0003473987      -0.0332056516      -0.3876872943       0.4004517246       0.5819525806       0.4606010167       0.0154445180 
#      age:subtest2       age:subtest3       age:subtest4 groupmale:subtest1 groupmale:subtest2 groupmale:subtest3 groupmale:subtest4 
#     -0.0096406797      -0.0243325126      -0.0220695291       0.0305993804      -0.3875935877       0.0188624440       0.1734536370 

Note how this gives you the same coefficient estimates as model_avg. But it tells you also something about how the age and group effects interact with the subtests. Another option could be fitting a mixed-effects model with random intercepts and slopes grouped by subtest.

thank you. I still don't get it. But they also have a different unit, you are just not seeing that unit . I couldn't get my head around it. How do I interpret "a 1-unit change in age adds 0.11 to the summed composite test score (or .0275 to the avg score)". In what units would I be talking about? I edited the post for clarification as well.

@LarissaCury The units are "score / test" for the average and "score / 5 tests" for the sum.

Can I say, for the summed scores as DP: in relation to fem, males decrease -0.16 in the total accuracy score across all 5 tests and, for avg: in relation to fem,  males decrease .0275 in the average accuracy score per test ? Are these correct interpretations?

Yes, but I would say "males scored lower by  ..." instead of "males decrease" and make it clear that those are marginal effects.

Thanks! In the case of avg scores, they're once again in units of SD, correct? As such, when I say males scored lower by .0275 in relation to fem , does that mean .0275 SDs ? What about the summed? @Roland

Yes, they are. I would not use the summed score.

And if the summed score is important for the research question, I would sum first and scale second. I believe that's what is commonly done for what is called "grading on a curve".
